# pull specific editable fields while the others are just displaying titles in django?

Tags: django

I tried my best with answers provided here but its just not working for me. I am trying to create forms that can edit the database instance. I would like to display a persons name to the left and an editable field to the right. At one point I managed to succeed doing it one instance at a time but I lost whatever luck I had there and can't replicate it. I would like to do this for several entries in the databse not just one. Heres the latest thing I tried, please help if you can:

model:

```
class listMem(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField (max_length = 20)
    last_name = models.CharField (max_length = 20)
    email = models.EmailField ()
    perform = models.BooleanField ()
    field_1 = models.BooleanField ()
    field_2 = models.BooleanField ()
    field_text = models.CharField (max_length = 50)
    field_num = models.CharField (max_length = 50)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, auto_now = False )
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = False, auto_now = True )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.first_name +" " + str(self.perform)
```

view:

```
def comp (request):

    dance_list = listMem.objects.all()

    dancer = listMem.objects.get(pk=1)
    form = listMemForm(instance=dancer)
    if form.is_valid():
        save_it = form.save(commit = False)
        save_it.save()
```

template:

```
 <form method='POST' action='#'> {% csrf_token %} 

        <ul>{% for f in form %}
<li>{% if f.instance.pk %}title: {{ f.instance.first_name }}
    {% endif %} {{ f }}</li>
    {% endfor %}</ul>

    <input type="submit" value="submit">


</form>
```

form:

```
class ListMemForm (forms.ModelForm):

        class Meta:
            model = listMem
            fields = ('last_name')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into creating a formset with django modelformset_factory: check the docs.

overview of how I'd do it

1. Remove the `dance_list = listMem.objects.all()` line , its unnecessary

2.Try:
     `listmemformset = modelformset_factory(listMem, form=ListMemForm)
      if request.method =='POST':
        formset=listmemformset(request.POST, request.FILES,
        queryset=listMem.objects.all() )
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
      else:
        formset = listmemformset(queryset=listMem.objects.all())`

1. in your template, be sure to included the `{{formset.management_form}}` before your for loop and style as you want.

Comment: Thank you so much, the spacing through me off a bit but overall it helped a lot